# react-hook-form doesn't recover from isSubmitting state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I make an API call in my submit handler (async function). In case of error, I show an alert and then re-throw from the catch block, so that monitoring tools like Sentry can report it.

To disable the submit button in the process, I use `formState.isSubmitting` returned by the `useForm` hook. I'd expect `isSubmitting` to turn false in case of both resolution or rejection of the Promise, but it stays true even upon rejection.

Here's the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-interceptor-react18-forked-89i3nq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/9879

"RHF doesn't support throwing errors in the submit handler with the current API design."